# Azure Apps JWT Authentication

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services, azure-api-apps, azure-api-management

I can't seem to find any documentation from Azure App Services on how to actually implement either:

1. Use a JWT for authentication/authorization (directly without using a session id)
2. Exchange a JWT for a session id

Docs show state that is it possible but nowhere do i find code examples.

Comment: Can you add a link to the docs you're referring to in your question?

Comment: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-app-service-authentication-authorization/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per #1 - i found this is the easiest approach for Azure based sites...

Simply put the autheticationToken token return into future header as

```
x-zumo-auth: [token]
```

Per #2 exchanging the auth code for a session ID - i think the simplest solution is to do the above to a webservice (include the x-zumo-auth header) and have the server return the SessionID from a web api call.

Answer (score 2):

For information on #1 (how to use a JWT directly), check out https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/08/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-5-custom-authentication/ - this uses a JWT directly for authentication using [Auth0](http://auth0.com) as a provider.

Answer (score 2):

There is also a sample that shows how to mint custom JWT tokens that work with the service. Have a look at https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/tree/master/samples/custom-authentication.